# Laravel 5.8 make:model with custom path

Tags: laravel-5, model, laravel-artisan

I am on Laravel 5.8. Need to make model to custom folder. So I tried some modification of make:model command but without success.

```
make:model Books --path=app/Model throws --path option does not exists

make:model Books app/Model throws too many arguments
```

So what is the right way to do it please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a model in a different path you can for example use:

```
php artisan make:model Model/Book
```

This will create your model `Book` in a folder `/app/Model/`. If the folder does not exist, it will be created.

Note: I'd suggest using the singular `Book` instead of `Books` as model name

Comment: Yes this works. Why Laravel changing interface so often?

Comment: Does it change that often? This works in Laravel5-7.  Feel free to accept as answer when you can. Thx

Comment: No I found a lot of solutions as I mentions in question. None on them mentioned this way.